# Proving $\lim\limits_{x\to a} |g(x)| = 0 \implies$ $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I am trying to prove:

> Let $g$ be a real valued function for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $a \ne x$ is such that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} |g(x)| = 0$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x) = 0$.

Proof:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)$ be a real valued function, and $a \ne x$ be such that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} |g(x)| = 0$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then, $\exists \delta>0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
        0<|x-a|<\delta \implies \left||g(x)|-0\right| = |g(x)| = |g(x)-0| < \epsilon
    \end{equation*}
and we conclude that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x) = 0$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: The term $a\neq x$ does not quite make sense as $x$ is the variable

Comment: Probabyl I would first write $$ 0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow ||g(x)|-0|<\epsilon,$$ than in the next line write those two equalities. (That being said, as of now I would still consider it correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is good, but the wording is not so good. First of all (and you have already been informed of this in the comments), it makes no sense to say that $a\ne x$. Then I would simply say that the assertion $\lim_{x\to a}|g(x)|=0$ means$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):|x-a|<\delta\implies\bigl||g(x)|\bigr|<\varepsilon,\tag1$$whereas the assertion $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$ means$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):|x-a|<\delta\implies|g(x)|<\varepsilon.\tag2$$But, since, for each $b\in\Bbb R$, $\bigl||b|\bigr|=|b|$, it is clear that, in fact, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the same statement.

So, this actually proves that$$\lim_{x\to a}|g(x)|=0\iff\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0.$$

Comment: Would it make more sense to say that "let $a$ be a limit point of $\mathbb{R}$"?

Comment: Not much, since *every* point of $\Bbb R$ is a limit point of $\Bbb R$. I suggest “Let $a$ be a limit point of the domain of $f$.”

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, but the phrasing of both the question and the proof is weird. Here's how I'd phrase the question:

> Let $g:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be a function, and let $a\in \Bbb{R}$. Show that if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}|g(x)| = 0$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x) = 0$.

Then, I'd phrase the proof like this:

> Let $a\in \Bbb{R}$, let $\epsilon > 0$. (By the hypothesis and definition of limit) there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$,
> \begin{align}
> 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies ||g(x)| - 0| < \epsilon\tag{$*$}
> \end{align}
> We now claim the same $\delta$ works for $g$ as well, because if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then
> \begin{align}
> |g(x)-0| &= |g(x)| = ||g(x)| - 0| < \epsilon. & \tag{by $*$}
> \end{align}
> (Since $\epsilon> 0$ was arbitrary, this shows exactly that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x) =0$.)

The stuff in brackets you can either choose to include or not, depending on how comfortable you are with limits/ who you are writing for etc.

Comment: For my edification, why do you consider the wording of my proof "weird"? Does it come off as unclear? I see how my wording of the question statement is weird.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson The first sentence of your proof has the same "weirdness" as the problem statement, because it makes no sense to say $a\neq x$ right from the beginning, and also another thing is that $g(x)$ is not a real-valued function. It is $g$ which is the real valued function; $g(x)$ is the real-number you obtain as an output when you evaluate the function $g$ on the input $x$. Apart from this, the rest of your proof idea is fine (it's just a matter of how explicit you wanna be in phrasing, for example mentioning that the same $\delta$ works in both situations etc).