# Is $\lim_{x\to a }|f(x)| = 0 \implies \lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$ a valid deduction for limits?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

i.e.
consider this question involving a multivariable limit: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2y^3\ln(1+x)}{x^4+y^6}.$$

Can I do $0≤\left| \frac{x^2y^3\ln(1+x)}{x^4+y^6}\right |≤|x^4+y^6||x^2y^3\ln(1+x)|$, and then finish off my working with the squeeze law and applying the deduction in the question?:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left| \frac{x^2y^3\ln(1+x)}{x^4+y^6}\right |=0 \implies \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2y^3\ln(1+x)}{x^4+y^6}=0$$

Comment: $\left|\frac{x^2y^3}{x^4+y^6}\right|\le\frac12$ ( $|ab|\le\frac{a^2+b^2}2, a:=x^2, b:=y^3$) and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}|\ln(1+x)|=0.$

Comment: On an intuitive level, the reason that you are allowed to **blur the distinction** between $~f(x) \to 0,~$ and $~|f(x)| \to 0,~$ is because the $~\epsilon, ~\delta~$ definition of a limit focuses on the *entire neighborhood* of radius $~\epsilon~$ around $~0.~$  This implies that the **blurred distinction** is built in to the $~\epsilon,~\delta,~$ definition of a limit.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3776979/42969

Answer (score 2):

In general you have

$$ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = l \iff \lim_{x \to a } \vert f(x)- l \vert = 0.$$

This follows immediately from the $\epsilon-\delta $ definition of the limit since

$$ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = l \iff   \forall \epsilon, \exists \delta : \vert x-a \vert < \delta \implies  \vert f(x)-l\vert < \epsilon.$$

and $\vert \;\vert f(x)- l \vert - 0 \vert= \vert f(x)- l \vert$ .

Answer (score 1):

Claim : $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=0$ implies $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0.$

We can prove this by $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

Suppose $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=0$ and we want to show $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. By the supposition, there is $\delta>0$ s.t. $0<|x-a|<\delta\implies ||f(x)|-0|<\epsilon.$

Then, assuming $0<|x-a|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-0|=|f(x)|=||f(x)|-0|<\epsilon.$

Thus $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0.$

---

In addition, by the similar method, we can also prove the opposite direction : $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$ implies $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=0.$